# Arduino Keybard Library

Tags: arduino, keyboard

I wrote this code:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
  Keyboard.begin();
  
  Keyboard.print("Hello!");
}
```

And Iam getting the error

```
C:\Users\nobody\sketch_feb12a\sketch_feb12a.ino: In function 'void setup()':
C:\Users\nobody\sketch_feb12a\sketch_feb12a.ino:4:3: error: 'Keyboard' was not declared in this scope
   Keyboard.begin();
   ^~~~~~~~

exit status 1

Compilation error: 'Keyboard' not found. Does your sketch include the line '#include <Keyboard.h>'?
```

I tried installing Keyboard.h from a zip and from the Library manager.

What do I have to change?

Comment: Keyboard library is not for Uno

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying this on a board that supports emulating USB devices, such as the Teensy, then you need to select keyboard option for USB Type:
`Tools > USB Type > Keyboard`

This library does not work for the Arduino Uno or similar boards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you use the board like Leonardo? If you try to compile code with keyboard for the board which doesn't support HID interface, you will get this error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).